# Send a MongoDB doc to clients anytime it changes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, database, nosql

I want send a Mongo doc to users anytime it changes. Basically what I need is to listen for change events and then when a document is changed it gets passed it into a function that broadcasts to the correct people.

Can I listen for change events somehow? Is there a better DB to do this type of thing?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection

Answer (score 2):

[SERVER-124](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-124) may be implemented someday. In the meantime, you can hook into a replication process. Basically, you should do what legitimate replication clients do: [tail](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tailable+Cursors) the `local.oplog` collection. It contains all data modifications, you filter them, pick only interesting and broadcast to clients.

See here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replication+Internals

Answer (score 1):

It's a planned feature. Vote for it here
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-124

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [mongo-oplog](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongo-oplog), which implements this in NodeJS by exploiting MongoDB's replication system.