# How to show queries in console log using sails?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am starting a project with sails and mysql, and I do'nt know how configurate it to show the queries executed in the console.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible with Sails at this time, although the feature has been requested.  Your best bet is to inspect the log file provided by your database:

Postgres: [How to log PostgreSQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgres-sql-queries)

MySQL: [Log all queries in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql)

MongoDB: [MongoDB logging all queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204341/mongodb-logging-all-queries)

Comment: Use the `LOG_QUERIES=true node myFile.js` mentioned below

Comment: LOG_QUERIES=true is not working any more with sails 1.1

Comment: This answer is no longer valid with Sails >= 1.1. See below.

Answer (score 24):

The mysql adapter has a debug variable LOG_QUERIES to send all queries to the console.

`LOG_QUERIES=true node myFile.js`

Comment: This works fine, that variable is in file: sails-mysql/lib/adapter.js
Thank you!!! :D

Comment: This work great thanks, @user1278519 and at mzalazar.

Comment: Note that this is an environment variable.

Answer (score 6):

This solution works for sails >= 1.1.

The [`sails-mysql`](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql) (as of v1.0.0) adapter uses the [`machinepack-mysql`](https://github.com/sailshq/machinepack-mysql) driver which logs queries to [`debug`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug). So all that's needed to log all native queries is to enable the debug flag:

```
DEBUG=query node app.js
```

Comment: It also works for sails-mssql/sails-sqlserver adapter.

Comment: this is the currently working solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing Sails.js development on Mac OS with [Postgresql.app](http://postgresapp.com/), you can enable all query logging as follows:

In a new Terminal, edit `~/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var/postgresql.conf` and set:

```
logging_collector = on
log_directory = 'pg_log'
log_statement = 'all'
```

Then restart Postgresql.app (click on menubar icon, Quit, then use Spotlight to relaunch).

Then tail the log with:

```
tail -F ~/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/var/pg_log/postgresql-2014-10-30_104957.log
```

You'll have to find the newest postgresql-*log to tail and substitute that above.

Comment: latest postgresql.app has the var folder named var-9.*

Answer (score 2):

My answer might me very late but just found a solution which might help people
sails version = 0.12.14

to log quires do following

navigate to
**node_modules\sails-mysql\lib\adapter.js**

locate variable declaration of "**log**"

then change "**process.env.LOG_QUERIES**" to "**sails.config.LOG_QUERIES**"

navigate to

**[sails root]/config/env/[development or production].js**

add

```
LOG_QUERIES = 'true',
```

NOTE :- remember to put ""or '' for **true**

Answer (score 1):

Or add log to sql module.

In mysql this is:

```
working_dir/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js

function **createQuery** (33)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put

> LOG_QUERIES = 'true'

in sails lift command

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your datastore

**debug: ["ComQueryPacket"]**

config/datastores.js should be look like this

```
module.exports.datastores = {
  default: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    user: '*****',
    password: "****",
    host: '*****',
    database: '****',
    debug: ["ComQueryPacket"]
  }
}
```