# MongoDB: How to log all queries to log file on Windows

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

This Questions could not help me: [MongoDB logging all queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204341/mongodb-logging-all-queries)

Here is my configuration file:

```
dbpath  = C:\mongodb\data
logpath = C:\mongodb\mongo.log
diaglog = 3                      
profile = 2
slowms  = 1
```

but my log file contains no queries. What I'm doing wrong?

P.S: I'm using mongodb version v3.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to increase your log verbosity.

1. Increase your log verbosity in configuration file. systemLog.component.query.verbosity = 4 see [systemLog.component.query.verbosity](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#systemLog.component.query.verbosity) documentation
2. db.setLogLevel(...)
   see [setLogLevel](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/#db.setLogLevel) documentation.

your final config file should look like

```
storage:
   dbPath: "C:\mongodb\data"

systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "C:\mongodb\mongo.log"
   component:
       query:
           verbosity: 2

operationProfiling:
    slowOpThresholdMs: 100
    mode: slowOp
```

Comment: ok got: `unrecognised option 'systemLog.component.query.verbosity'`

Comment: @dit what version of mongo are you running?

Comment: @dit try increasing the verbosity with the sytnax used here (https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/configuration-options/#systemlog-options)

Answer (score 0):

Connect from the mongo shell and run:
db.setLogLevel(2,"query")