# Mongodb list previous queries

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to find a list of previous actions towards Mongodb?

I have a Mongodb on a linux server and some suspicious queries might've been executed, is there any way to show list of previous queries?

I called these  two methods:

```
db.getProfilingStatus()
db.getProfilingLevel()
```

Output:

> { "was" : 0, "slowms" : 100 }
>
> 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB does not log **any** database operations by default.

In order to log **every** operations done by the service you have to either
Set profiling level in the config file and restart service

```
operationProfiling:
   mode: all
```

or run the following command in the database instance (does not persist after service restart)

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

Note that this is for development porpuses only cuz this will slows down your database service.

Comment: would you provide more details?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204341/mongodb-logging-all-queries

Comment: Is there alterntive? My profiling level was set to 0

Comment: I don't know any other solution. If you think your database is compromised you should manually check your database for suspicious data like new admin users added to the users collection, etc

Comment: Could you please update your answer with more info about it  so I can accept it as good answer?