# Why mongodb.log does not have detailed log, for example update, delete, insert log?

Tags: mongodb

Why mongodb.log does not have detailed log, for example  `update, delete, insert` sql log?

Comment: I can not find the same question,Could you help me  provide the link? Thank you!

Comment: Is you question [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15204341/2185245)? It has some suggestions which might help.

Comment: @Abhishek,   thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB logging all queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204341/mongodb-logging-all-queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. set the profiling level  `db.setProfilingLevel(2)`
   2.Check Profiling Level `db.getProfilingStatus()`  result `{ "was" : 2, "slowms" : 100 }`
2. get logresult `db.system.profile.find()`

[image]

refer to:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-profiler/

Answer (score 1):

Logging all the operations would have a big impact on your database performance, that 's why by default nothing is log.

However, you can play with the database profiler if you really want them.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

Comment: Thanks for your reply!