# MongoDB how to check if integer value is increased?

Tags: c#, mongodb, winforms, mongodb-query

I need to check integer value is increased or decreased from MongoDB.
How can I do that?
By the way I'm using MongoDB change streams.

[Here is my collection snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnUQU.png)

Comment: increased or decreased from what?

Comment: I added before integer value but now when I check this value, value is increased. How can I catch this update?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927732/why-mongodb-log-does-not-have-detailed-log-for-example-update-delete-insert-l