# MongoDB with Spring data - Duplicated query from driver

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm having a duplicate query when performing a simple query. The files:

SomeClass.java:

```
@Document(collection = "someCollection")
public class SomeClass {

    private String _id;
    private String someField;

    //...
}
```

SomeClassRepository.java:

```
@Repository
public interface SomeClassRepository extends MongoRepository<SomeClass, String> {
}
```

Service.java:

```
@Autowired
private SomeClassRepository someClassRepository;

public SomeClass find(String id){
    return someClassRepository.findOne(id);
}
```

application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=DEBUG
```

Log file:

```
14:14:46.514 [qtp1658534033-19] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : "40c23743-afdb-45ca-9231-c467f8e8b320"} fields: null for class: class com.somepackage.SomeClass in collection: someCollection
14:14:46.534 [qtp1658534033-19] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : "40c23743-afdb-45ca-9231-c467f8e8b320"} in db.collection: someDatabase.someCollection
```

I also tried to:

1) use @Id annotation with a field named "someId"
2) use @Id annotation with a field named "id"
3) use a field named "id" (without @Id annotation)

Unfortunately, I always have two queries to the database.

Anyone knows how to perform a single query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its only single query that is sent to database.  Your log messages are coming from two different places.

First place : `doFindOne` method - [`link`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/2.0.5.RELEASE/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.java#L2187); Second place : 
`FindOneCallback` class - [`link`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/2.0.5.RELEASE/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.java#L2619)

You can also confirm the logs by looking at db logs. More info [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21726027/2683814)