# Slow queries for MongoDB regular expression text in Java

Tags: java, regex, spring, mongodb

When searching for regular expression text in MongoDB, the speed is slow at first, so I would like to know the cause.

Only on the phenomenon JAVA Application Server will the corresponding slow query be found.

When the corresponding query is run in the MongoDB shell, it works very fast (index works well).

The number of data result values in the above query is five.
The total number of data in the collection is 450,000

Below is a process-specific query.

=====JAVA Process=====
(Very Slow 5,518ms)

```
public List<Contents> findContentList(int rowCnt, long rowNo, String searchContent){
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria((Criteria.where(DictionaryKey.content).regex("^" + searchContent)));
        if (rowNo > 0) query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(DictionaryKey.contentSeq).gt(rowNo));
        query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, DictionaryKey.contentSeq));
        query.limit(rowCnt);

        return this.mongoTemplate.find(query, Contents.class, Constant.CollectionName.Contents);
       
}
```

java Monitoring tool

```
   Query : Query: { "content" : { "$regex" : "^abcd"}}, Sort: { "contentSeq" : 1}
    Collection Name : contents
    MongTemplate#find() [5,518ms] -- org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mongTemplate.find()Ljava/util/List;
```

=====Mongodb Shell======
Mongodb query (Very Fast, index works well)

```
db.contents.found ({content:{"$regex" : "^abcd"}}).sort ({"contentSeq" : 1});
```

'contents' collection index is `content_1_contentSeq_1`

Please help me.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56159506/6267549 - it's slow because Spring is mapping through 2 levels.

Comment: When monitored, it wasn't a marshalling issue. It took a long time to get data from the network.

Comment: If possible please post the actual Java code.

Comment: @prasad_  
Added Java code to content.

Comment: The Java code looks okay. Are you accessing the same database/ data/collection from the `mongo` shell?

Comment: @prasad_
The mongo router(Mongos) IP used by the application server and
Mongo router(Mongos) of Mongo shell that I tested is different from each other.
But the replica set is the same.

The singularity occur once per 5minutes.
It doesn't happen every time.

Additionally, it occurs more and more frequently when users have a lot of access in only those queries.

Comment: @prasad_
All queries except for those queries are OK.
CPU and IOPS are also stable.

What's unique is that
That is, there is a delay in the query every five minutes. It doesn't happen every time.

The query has a delay every for five minutes.
It doesn't happen every time.

Comment: SInce you are using `mongos` your cluster is sharded. Is the collection sharded?

Comment: @prasad_ 
No
This Collection is not sharded

Comment: This is from the docs: [regex and index usage](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html#index-use).

Comment: @prasad_ 
Thank you. Let me check the document again.

Comment: What is `db.contents.found` ?

Comment: My guess is you are not actually executing the query in the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason

The cause is that some queries are using the wrong index.

The solution was to force the use of the index by giving a hint.