# How to count number of read/write/delete operations in mongo for a period?

Tags: mongodb

I need to find out how many entity writes/reads or deletes a mongo cluster does within a specific period for internal metrics.

Only found **db.currentOp().inprog.length** which counts current op log.

Obviously, would be great if I don't need to do it through code, but from the sharded cluster out of the box system.

Later edit: logging all queries will be another option, but not for my production DB as it's too much and I need to do it over a 30 days period at least to have a good average

Comment: Would logging all queries be close enough? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204341/mongodb-logging-all-queries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB logging all queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204341/mongodb-logging-all-queries)

Comment: no, because it will probably fill the db within a day. I have about 2-3k/second.

Comment: how about using [mongostat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongostat/)