# Does Mongo DB write everyting into oplog

Tags: mongodb

In Oracle developers can run sqls in nologging mode. Is it possible on Mongo DB or Mongo DB writes all operations into the oplog(operations log)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204341/mongodb-logging-all-queries

Answer (score 0):

A standalone server (not part of replica set or sharded cluster) does not employ the oplog.

Comment: We have replicas. I wonder when there are replicas, does oplog includes all operations? Is there any exception?

Comment: If you are trying to achieve something, edit the question with your goals.