# Listen for changes in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to run a batch script when changes occur on a MongoDB collection.

Is there any way to listen changes in a collection? Similar to `trigger` in Oracle. Or is there any way to run a batch file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to listen for changes to a MongoDB collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection)

Comment: You may create a tailable cursor on `oplog` to listen to any changes in your database.