# Update computed field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo document with several fields -

```
User: { paid_visits: 10, free_visits: 10, totalLength: 120, avgRevenue: 4.4 }
```

I update the visits and the total length automatically, but in order to compute the avgRevenue, I need to do a computation based on  totalLength, paid_visits and free_visits.

Currently I need to get the user, compute the avgRevenue, and then update it.

What I would like to do is to update the avgRevenue every time I update any other field. How can I do that?

Comment: Have a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not have any server-side support for triggers, but irrespective this requirement seems like something you could best handle in your application model since it is limited to a specific document type.

If you are using a framework/ODM they often support or hooks based on various trigger points in the lifecycle of your request.

For example, the Mongoid ODM for Ruby has a number of useful [callbacks](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/callbacks.html#callbacks) that allow you to invoke application logic at appropriate points such as `before_save` for a document.  Your callback could check if any of the dependent fields have changed and only do the `avgRevenue` recalculation if required.