# How to enable auditing and log all CRUD operations in MongoDB Node App?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a node mongo app. Now I want to show audit trail for some specific crud events which are happening in the application.

What would be the best approach for solving this problem ?

I have considered of creating a new collection and service which would be called in each method in node app for logging the operations.

Answer (score 5):

It's better to use a different schema having all the logs that you want to store  for particular actions.

```
// schema
var schema = new Schema({
    actionType: {type: String, require: true},
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    userType: { type: String, required: true },
    message: { type: String, required: true },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },

}, options);
```

Here you can log your activity logs with

> What action have been taken.
>   Which user.
>   And the message that you want to store with that action etc.

Answer (score 4):

You are talking about 'triggering'. But unfortunately "MongoDB does not support triggers".

For solving your issue simply create another collection and store the log information into that collection.

Reference :

- [does mongodb have the properties such as trigger and procedure in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629462/does-mongodb-have-the-properties-such-as-trigger-and-procedure-in-a-relational-d)
- [How to listen for changes to a MongoDB collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 1):

you can add a middleware to you app which adds a [bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan) child logger to each request with some unique id (probably `uuid`)

here is some sample code to attach a logger to each request with unique id,
whenever you will print something using this logger, this uuid will also be printed automatically so you can trace each request using this id

```
var bunyan = require('bunyan');
var uuid = require('uuid');
var logger = bunyan.createLogger({name: 'some name'});
function loadlogger(req, res, next) {
    req.log = logger.child({request_id: uuid.v4()});
    next()
}
app.use(loadLogger);
```

and you can log when ever you want as follow

```
req.log.info({keys: values}, "message");
req.log.warn({keys: values}, "message");
req.log.error({keys: values}, "message");
```

You can refer to complete documentation [bunyan logger](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mongoose module then there is method for logging all query.It'll log all queries on console.

```
mongoose.set('debug', true);
```

If you want to log in a file then use callback for this method

```
mongoose.set('debug', function (coll, method, query, doc [, options]) {
 //do your thing
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions of mongodb (>=3.6) you can use mongodbs change stream.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/

Based on that, you can track your changes you want and may save them separately in a file or a collection.

Here is a quick example:

```
const collection = db.collection('users');
const changeStream = collection.watch();
changeStream.on('change', next => {
  // do your stuff
});
```