# Pushing the data as soon as update happens in db through Node.js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, events, long-polling

Is there any way to push the data onto the web as soon as some data are updated into the DB instead of polling do we have some events which can check whenever some data is updated into the DB. I am dealing with some 5,60,000 records on DB so whenever any stock data gets changed i have to push a message onto the web.

So i have been told to do it with Node.js. I tried it but it was a kind of long polling in which i have to set the time and after that period it will continuously hit the db and fetch the updated data. Is there other way to do it instead of polling like a kind of some update event.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection is of value to you?

Comment: They are also using a kind of polling mechanism by making the thread to sleep for 1 second, I feel is there any way like an event thing for DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want there are two problems you should solve :

1. The connexion Node <=> Database
2. The connexion Node <=> Webpage

The first problem depends on the database you are using. For example if you are using Postgres  you should check http://bjorngylling.com/2011-04-13/postgres-listen-notify-with-node-js.html
or in the case of mongoDB you should check https://github.com/TorchlightSoftware/mongo-watch
There are probably similar solutions for other databases as well.

The second problem is what NodeJS does best : a seamless connexion between the webpage and the server is easily achieved using SocketIO : http://socket.io/ which allows Node to send update events with the new data to to your webpage, without the hassle of long polling.

Comment: I am using socket.io also , Similar to mongo-watch is there any library for MySql DB also so for any insert or update it should trigger an event .