# How to observe a (mongo) collection in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, observer-pattern, observers

Observable ([docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/observer/rdoc/Observable.html)) only seems to watch individual objects.

What is a good way to observe a collection, and call a method whenever a document is created, updated, or deleted?

Working in Ruby 2.1.2 (without Rails), Mongo and Mongoid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to listen for changes to a MongoDB collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there may be a method for achieving this detailed within the following thread: [How to listen to changes to a MongoDB collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10325343/343495)

Comment: That answer requires making the collection a [capped collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/), which comes with some significant limitations on the capability of the collection. Another solution is to use tailable cursors with the [oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) (which is a capped collection).