# better solution than timertask with scala in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I need to regularly check the database for updated records. I currently use TimerTask which works fine. However, I've found its efficiency is not good and consumes a lot of server resouces. Is there a solution which can fulfill my requirement but is better?

```
def checknewmessages() = Action{
    request =>
       TimerTask(5000){
         //code to check database
       }
}
```

Comment: What kind of database are you using ? and what do you want to do when things change - trigger some other event ?

Comment: Does this need to return a value..?

Comment: @m-z, no it doesn't. It just adds the record to the channel when new records found.

Comment: @Soumya Simanta i use mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two solutions:

1. You can use the ReactiveMongo driver for Play which is completely non-blocking and async and capped collection in Mongo DB.

Please see this for an example - 
https://github.com/sgodbillon/reactivemongo-tailablecursor-demo
[How to listen for changes to a MongoDB collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection)

2. If you are using a database that doesn't support a push mechanisms you can implement that using an Actor by scheduling messages to itself at regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

If your logic is in your database (stored procedures etc) you could simply create a cron job.

You could also create a command line script that encapsulates the logic and schedule (cron again).

If you have your logic in your web application, you could again create a cron job that simply makes an API call to your app.