# Listen for insertion to an embedded document in MongoDB using Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm creating a ruby based tool of callback listeners for Restful applications that emit callbacks, so that I can access the callback emitted out, something like RequestBin. For the backend I have MongoDB where I have 1 main document which creates a reusable bucket per session to listen to requests and I have an embedded document which is populated per request.

```
class Bin
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    embeds_many :callbacks
    field :bin_id, type: String
end

class Callback
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    embedded_in :bin, :inverse_of => :bins
    field :callback_id, type: Integer
    field :http_method, type: String
    field :params, type: String
    field :headers, type: String
    field :raw_post, type: String
end
```

My question is there a way of to listen for insertion of callback document in MongoDB?
I have looked around on internet and found that MongoDB has what is called `capped collections` and `tailable cursors` that allows MongoDB to push data to the listeners. But for me it will not work as I have the main document already created and I have to listen to the creation of embedded document.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for MongoDB triggers.  They do not exist in any official way - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Nope.  There is no way to listen for document changes in MongoDB.

Search for "mongodb triggers" to learn more.

[How to listen for changes to a MongoDB collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection)

Comment: Thanks maerics for reply.I looked into link you have provided, but answer given there is using capped collection and in my case I don't have a capped collection element and moreover I want to listen to the changes of the embedded document.

Comment: @harshs08: correct - the answer is "no, you cannot do what you want".

Comment: Thank you. I wish there would have some way to do that as querying again and again to check for some document existence is kind of expensive.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up doing the following,

```
  def self.wait_for_callback(bin_id)
    host = ENV['MONGO_RUBY_DRIVER_HOST'] || 'localhost'
    port = ENV['MONGO_RUBY_DRIVER_PORT'] || MongoClient::DEFAULT_PORT

    db = MongoClient.new(host, port).db('mongoid')
    coll = db.collection('bins')
    retries = 0

    res = coll.find("bin_id" => bin_id).to_a.first
    loop do
      if res["callbacks"].nil? && retries < 45
        sleep 5
        puts "Retry: #{retries}"
        retries += 1
        res = coll.find("bin_id" => bin_id).to_a.first
      else
        return res["callbacks"].to_a.first       
      end
    end
    return nil
  rescue Exception => e
    @@success =false
    @@errors << "Error:\n#{e.inspect}"
    if $debug_flag == "debug"
      puts @@errors 
   end
    return nil
  end
```

But here the problem is have do repeated querying. So is there a better way to do this?