# Does mongodb provide triggers, like in RDBMS?

Tags: mongodb, triggers

Can we able to write trigger in mongodb, and is there any mechanisam we can achive notifier or concept like trigger in mongodb ? does it affect performace of mongodb ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection