# How to check if the database has changed [Mongodb][Nodejs]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

Is there any built-in method that i can use to check if the data in the  database has changed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to listen for changes to a MongoDB collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection)

Comment: but is there any method other than the tailable cursors?

Comment: @Nisthar In short: No. A bit longer: I usually implement an [observer pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern): Before or after I change the data in my service layer, I notify the observers.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, thnx.it would be easy if there is any built-in method in mongoose or some other libs.

Comment: There is a module for implementing the observer pattern in node.js

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, Whts module name? and how to implement?