# SignalR Database polling with mongodb in an asp.net environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, signalr

I currently have 3 applications that access the same database. One of the applications writes into it, the other one needs to be notified in real time once and update to the database has been made. Unfortunately I cannot seem to find a way to make this work. I was wondering if you guys knew of any solution.

edit: Despite the possible duplicate offers a hacky solution, I am looking for a proper way to handle the cursor/connection and set this up in C#, not PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to listen for changes to a MongoDB collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection)