# Change notification in MongoDB:using mongo-connector

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

Linking to this question [How to listen for changes to a MongoDB collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection) and other similar post here; my requirement is also same: listen to MongoDB for data changes and take some action in my .NET Business layer (probably refresh data ... etc).

searching through different SO post, MongoDB documents, GitHub repository I could find that my best option is to get the required change in `OPLOG` using `Tailable Cursor`.

Other that that, I see `mongo-connector` which can be used to get change notification but I see target system is only `solr / ElasticSearch / another MongoDB cluster`.

My question: can I use `mongo-connector` in .NET/C# application to get change notification? Have anyone tried that? it's bit confusing and so thought of posting a question here.

If anyone have already tried, then can you provide a sample code (OR) to some resource which will provide a idea as "How to start...".

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I try to share an idea anyway.

Note: I've only started to look into `mongo-connector` and its capabilities, so my knowledge is a bit limited.

Nevertheless, the `mongo-connector` has an extension point called `DocManager`, this entity has basic CRUD methods and provides a way to get notified when your domain entities changes.

So for example you can [write your own `DocManager`](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Writing-Your-Own-DocManager). Changes you're interested in (i.e. document update) can trigger specific endpoints in your application. Or if you using some messaging in your application like `RabbitMQ` you can push those changes to messaging queue and implement different consumers, where each one of them will listen to specific messages.