# MongoDB value propagation between collections

Tags: mongodb, triggers, propagation

Is it possible to propagate changed values between collections?
Like, 1 collection contains values that refer to a day and other collection that refers to a week and contains a sum of the daily values.

```
{
  day: 1,
  values: {
    1: 0.2,
    2: 0.3,
    ..
 }
}

{
  week: 1,
  days: {
    1: 0.9,
    2: 0.3,
    ..
 }
}
```

Is there a way that by changing the daily values, the weekly values are updated accordingly?

Hope I made myself clear, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for DB trigger then MongoDB doesnot support triggers. But your scenario can be addressed using [Capped Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/) and [Tailable triggers](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/tailable-cursors/) or you can use the mongo trigger please see https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-triggers.

One of this approach will help you in solving your problem.

Reference:
[How to listen for changes to a MongoDB collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection)

Hope it Helps!