# How do you know data has been new added in your MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an nodejs server running witch show data on a web interface. The data is fetched from a MongoDB using mongoose. The data is added via an node-red application witch is isolated from the rest.

Currently my nodejs server fetches the data every 5 seconds. Is there a way to know if the data in my MongoDB has changed?

Thanks, I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you have access to a User Interface for MongoDB or are you doing this via code or on a remote server?

Comment: Try reading about ETags

Comment: @RobLang All of my code is running in docker containers. So i don't have acces to an UI (i think).

Comment: do you want see UI view of your mangodb data?

Comment: @craig No that is not my goal, my goal is to not fetch data every 5 seconds but only when data in my MongoDB has changed.

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for something similar to what you are asking for few months back. Few ways which i know to do it are:

1) You can try to use middlewares while inserting your documents in DB. You can then send that new data either after saving it in DB or at the time of insertion only.

2) [Refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10325343/4394926) which talks about solving your problem using inbuilt functions provided by mongoDb. You can study in deep about them in mongoDb docs.

3) There is also another way to do this which includes listening to changes in log files. As you know everything done in mongo is recorded and logged in files so whenever there is some change in data you can know it from there also. You will have to do the digging by yourself in this method.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it!