# How to apply SHA256/SHA512 to fields and store both forms?

Tags: mongodb, sha512, database

I have a field in Mongodb that contains large amounts of user data.

I need to apply SHA256 or SHA512 to the contents of the field while keeping the original.

I need another field to be generated with the SHA values of the original field.

I would like to automate this task, does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: There are some possible recommendations on this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection?noredirect=1&lq=1) that might work for you. However, if your collection is being updated by a program, then it might be easier to add the extra logic in there.

Comment: So? Just make a script to read through the collection, calculate the hashes and store the new fields.