# How to get inserted or updated documents only in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB in my web API. MongoDB is being updated/inserted by other sources.

How do I query mongodb to get only newly inserted or updated documents ?

I can get sorted documents by below query but this doesn't solve my purpose

```
db.collectionName.findOne({}, {sort:{$natural:-1}})
```

Is there any log or other way like in SQL there is `INSERTED` and `UPDATED`

Answer (score 0):

What are these newly inserted/updated documents in your context?

Assuming that you need to fetch newly/inserted documents relative to a time, you need to have a field in your collection that holds the time stamp (for example, inserted, and lastUpdated fields), you have an [operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) to help with updating. But this needs application changes.

Or you can use [change streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection), for a trigger like functionality. You can listen for changes and take actions as changes are made.