# Automatically setting a modified datetime when updating a record

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to automatically set a a modified date when performing an update? Or does this have to be done programmatically?

Comment: I see triggers [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/triggers/) but looks like specific to stitch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection

Comment: @titogeo - This may be workable but wouldn't this mean I'd effectively have to update the documents twice? 

Once for the initial update and again with the timestamp afterwards.

Comment: Yes, Or else use some application frameworks ( like for Java there is spring-data-mongo).  This will update records on the fly (before actual write to DB) without needing to update twice. And I think its same for all databases.

Comment: @MarkWalsh I’d say that heavily depends on your data model. `db.yourcoll.update(foo,{bar:baz,updated:now})` should work just fine.

Comment: That would require me to modify every single one of my update statements.  I was looking for a way to track this automatically.