# Is it possible to simulate realtime database "equivalent to firebase" in Vue, Vuex, Node

Tags: node.js, socket.io, vuejs2, vuex

I am creating a Vuejs app with Vuex store, I would like to synchronise database in realtime, maybe using sockets.io or similar realtime engine. I am using Node as a server, MongoDB for Storage. Any recommendations? I don't want to pay for Firebase :|
All Suggestions, are appreciated.

I tried to setup the environment, but I can use the help.

Comment: with mongodb you can listen for changes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection

Comment: I was hoping to trigger vuex getters or a similar functionality to reflect the changes for the connected clients, hence, sockets seemed like a solution

Comment: Check out https://deepstreamhub.com it might provide what you're looking for and works with mongo.

Comment: I’ll give it a try. Thanks