# Listen for update operation in mongoDB and update certain field automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

whenever any update operation occur on the collection, there should be an automated process in nodejs that will automatically update the timestamp for **updateAt** field.

I don't want to do manually as there are multiple sources from it can be updated.

MongoDB don't have any trigger, but there is a watch in MongoDB how can I use it.... I want to perform update operations inside the watch and don't want to trigger watch when we update it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is too broad - you need to ask about a specific programming problem you are having, and generally should include information about what you have already tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use post update hooks described [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post) 
But for this particular purpose, you can use `{
    timestamps: true
}`
in your mongoose schema and it will automatically update the createdAt and updatedAt fields

If you are not using mongoose take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection).

Comment: Thanks, but we are not using the mongoose.

Comment: Take a look at the link I added to the answer