# A loop that check if time is expired in database python

Tags: python, mongodb, loops, date, events

So I want to make a loop that keeps checking the database and make action if something has changed.

What i'm trying to make is somewhat like a mute system in mongodb. Where I give records an expiry date of the mute length. Which I already did with creating an index option called [`expireAfterSeconds`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/). But my problem is I want to make a python script to keep check if the record has expired with using less memory & cpu resources of making mongodb queries.

I have an idea *(inefficient solution)* and I think it can work but I think it's inefficient because it uses a lot of mongodb queries. And my solution is to make a `while` loop in python that keeps making mongodb queries to check if the record has expired or not.

But is there any other solutions that doesn't use a lot of queries or making a loop?
And I'm not that good with event driven loops so can someone suggest me another solution to this or should I just stick to my solution?

Sorry for my bad explanation I hope someone can get it.
Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to do if it is expired? this may help https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

Comment: This works fine but I want to make an action in python if the record has been expired.

Comment: "I want to make an action in python"  can you be more specific

Comment: So if the record got deleted from mongodb then I want python to execute a function to do something and indicate or print that this record has been expired

Comment: this will help pymongo [change_stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection)

Comment: This definitely may be what I'm looking for. I'm gonna close this question if it worked with me. Thanks!